# Wildcard for meta description in Joomla

Tags: metadata, joomla3.0, meta-tags

I am wondering if there's a way that I can easily change the month in some Joomla Menus meta title and description.

I thought maybe I could use some sort of wildcard that I could change (somewhere).

So say I put in `(*&&)` it would display as "October 2017" and then I could change it on the 1st of every month.

I have hundreds that would need changing monthly otherwise and it would be rather time consuming.

Comment: I just found this for Yoast in Wordpress >> https://yoast.com/titles-meta-variables - This is what I need but for Joomla

Answer (score 0):

The free or paid version of [Regular Labs ReReplacer](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/rereplacer) could be used for this.

Comment: Thank you Neil - I really appreciate this.